# How to find array items that begin with a number and return it in reverse alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
console.log(f(['12dh', '8-4', '66']))
//output should be => ['8-4', '66', '12dh']
```

Comment: Array.sort will help you

Comment: console.log(['12dh', '8-4', '66'].reverse())   will give you reverse sort order.  But your expected output above is not reverse alphabetical.  It is something else.  Reverse alphabetical would yield: ["66", "8-4", "12dh"].   If you need something custom, you'll have to write a sort function.   See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easily with `sort` and `reverse`.

```
var array = ['12dh', '8-4', '66'];

var sorted = array.sort().reverse();

console.log(sorted);
```

You can also wrap it in a function.

```
function sortReverse(array){
    return array.sort().reverse();
}
```

Also if you're concerned about performance you can pass a custom comparison function to `sort`:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
   return a < b;
});
```

This could be quicker when dealing with larger arrays, because it doesn't have to reverse after sorting.

To filter anything that doesn't start with a number:

```
array.filter(function(str){
   return !isNaN(str.charAt(0));
}).sort().reverse();
```

Comment: HI, if the array has some strings too like ['12dh', '8-4', '66', 'bvc','-abc'] as items how would you separate the items that start with the number alone and return them

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
var array = ['12dh', '8-4', '66'];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a < b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

I hope that helps :D